# Load the content dynamically by hijax

Tags: php, jquery, hijax

I want to load the page without refreshing. While preferring ajax technique the URL won't crawl in SEO. So I am choosing Hijax techinique to change the content without reload. I am new to this technique. So Kindly anyone suggest the guide for this. Also Say whether it support the dynamic content load? Because I am choosing the content based on the primary key value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar using JQuery alone.

If you attach an onClick to the links on your website, the search engines won't be able to trigger them as they are JS meaning that they can crawl properly. For a JS enabled browser you can catch the onClick, get the URL of the link clicked and then load that using AJAX into a div of your choice.

Here is the JS I used:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.ajax_link").click(function(e){
        ajaxLink(this, e);
    });
});

function ajaxLink(item, e) {
    var container = $("#ajax_container_wrapper");
    var link;

    if (e != null) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    link = $(item).attr("href");
    container.load(link);
}
```

And the hyperlink would be something like:

```
<a href="www.example.com" class="ajax_link">My Link</a>
```

This will load `www.example.com` into the `ajax_container_wrapper` div when the link is clicked. If you only want to load a portion of `www.example.com` then you can substitute this line:

```
link = $(item).attr("href");
```

with something like this:

```
link = $(item).attr("href") + " #some_div";
```

This will load the content of `some_div` on `www.example.com` into your `ajax_container_wrapper`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please give the code for my reference. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Ok no worries, will add some examples now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try this one.

Comment: Is there any option there to change the url also without refreshing using this method?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The URL is determined by the link being clicked so you just need to make sure your hyperlinks have the correct URLs which should be the case anyway as the search engines need to follow that link.

Comment: Basically all you need to do is add `class="ajax_link"` to your existing hyperlinks and make sure the JS is on your page.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. You gave valuable ideas for this issue